# Check Augur market validity in solidity contract

Tags: solidity, augur

I'm trying to validate my market created through my node on Rinkeby Testnet.

I created some markets on Rinkeby Testnet (using Augur.js) running my own Rinkeby Augur node.
When I get the markets created by me address (using Augur.js) one of the addresses is the following contract address:

> 0xac5c22dc5e67a07ba6fafd49aff8c41c810328ca

I want to check if the market is valid by using the following function:

```
function checkMarketValidity (
    address _augur,
    address _market
)
public 
payable
    public 
returns (bool)
{
    IMarket market = IMarket(_market);
    IAugur augur = IAugur(_augur);

    bool validity = augur.isValidMarket(market);
    return validity;
}
```

When I call this function using truffle (`truffle test --network rinkeby`):

```
const { receipt } = await contract.checkMarketValidity(AUGUR_ADDRESS_RINKEBY, MARKET_ADDRESS_RINKEBY);
```

The transaction gets reverted within the `augur.isValidMarket` function it seems like.

EDIT: My augur and market instances are able to get and verify the markets universe and this is all correct, for some reason the market transaction still reverts when trying to validate the market.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the repo for Augur V2 instead of Augur V1 (https://github.com/AugurProject/augur-core), Augur V1 is the currently live version of augur so I was using contracts that did not match up with the live contracts.